# make a flat to list to a embedded list python

Tags: python, list

I have a question on how to transfer a flat list to a embedded list.
For example,

```
['a','b','c'] => [['a'],['b'],['c']]
```

Instead of using for loop, I am looking for some other ways to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why no loops? Even a list comprehension is a loop.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid iteration here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehension should be considered even though a loop

```
res = [[i] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']

print(list(map(list, lst)))
# [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

Comment: But `map` won't yield results without iteration, right (which you are doing with `list()`)?

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker, yeah it does. But the good thing with `map` is that it can be lazy, though nothing significant about that here.

Comment: Quite true. I do like the lazy part about a map